# Monitor text file for changes with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, io

Right now, when I click a button a perl script is executed server-side. That script writes to a text file as it's executing.

I need to be able to monitor the text file for changes and write them to a div on the current page. This should continue until a predetermined 'end' sequence is found.

Comment: My thoughts are to use javascript to execute a while loop that reads in the most recent change and appends it to the div. This loop will execute until the most recent change is equal to the break statement (e.g. 'script finished').

Comment: you can do a HEAD ajax request on the text file to get the Last-Modified date, and if newer than last time, fetch it using GET. even faster would be to have notifications pushed to the client upon updating via an always-open socket or SSE to avoid polling and refresh granularity.

Answer (score 0):

Use document.getElementById("id") and append to specified area like equals to div area ,  and do not forget to use a loop to search for the recent change .